# Are there any open data sources on business strategy?

Tags: data-request, finance, business

I am looking for data on strategy selection and impact on financial results.
Data from the strategy models used in the analysis would also be very useful indeed.

Most of the data I can find is in 'case studies' created by MBA students; but it seems there is not a database compiling this research